# Using Regex in a Converter

Tags: c#, regex

I have Converter where I want to use Regex to split my ConverterParameters. The following can be the case, it's leading with:

```
<
<=
>
>=
==
!=
```

and after that a numer, for example

```
10.4565
```

Now I want to split this in two Matches on the Operator to compare and the Number. How can I do this?
I have tried this:

```
((==)|(!=)|(>)|(<)|(>=)|(<=) )|((?<=[><(==)(!=)(>=)(<=)])[0-9.]+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([<>]|[<>=!]=)\s*([0-9.]+)
```

---

Yours had a few issues: `((==)|(!=)|(>)|(<)|(>=)|(<=) )|((?<=[><(==)(!=)(>=)(<=)])[0-9.]+)`

- `[><(==)(!=)(>=)(<=)]` is a char class, it's equivalent to `[(!><=)]`
- The lookbehind was useless.

---

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"([<>]|[<>=!]=)\s*([0-9.]+)");
string s = @"<= 10.4568";
var matches = r.Matches(s);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Operator {match.Groups[1]}, number: {match.Groups[2]}");
}
```

Will output:

> Operator <=, number: 10.4568

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easiest:

```
(==|!=|>|<|>=|<=)\s*([0-9\.-]+)
```

It matches strings like "(operator) (number)".

Comment: `.` means a dot inside a char class, you don't need to escape it

Answer (score -1):

Ok here is what I've come up so far

`^(<=|>=|!=|==|>|<)(-?\d*\.?\d*$)`
tested with

```
!=-12322.645642
==12322
>=12
>=0.1
```

this is invalid: `==0..21`

this is also invalid

```
>--0.01
```

If you also want to allow whitespace between the operator and the number you can do this: `^(<=|>=|!=|==|>|<)(\s?-?\d*\.?\d*$)`